# Git: generate reverse patch

Tags: git

I generate a patch from a staged file (only one file) like this

```
git diff --cached > test/patch.diff
```

Now I can apply this patch in reverse using `git apply --cached --reverse`, but what I want is to generate a patch that is reversed beforehand.

More specifically, can I generate a "reversed" patch that I could apply with

```
git apply --cached
```

without explicitly specifying `--reverse`?

Comment: Try `git diff -R --cached`.

Comment: `git diff --cached -R`?

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I searched for `reverse` in the docs and never found the flag entry saying `Swap two inputs; that is, show differences from index or on-disk file to tree contents.`